# Read-Host Printing the data if the input is given from file | Ubuntu 16

Tags: powershell, io, read-host

I am experiencing issues with Read-Host when I am trying to read input from file

Let's say I create a file read.pwsh having the following contents

```
$a = Read-Host;
```

and there is input file `input.in` having the following content

```
hello
```

After executing command on terminal
pwsh **read.pwsh < input.in**

then I am getting the following output
hello
The above behaviour seems to be incorrect

**Expected behavior**

```
pwsh read.pwsh < input.in

this should not print anything
```

**Actual behavior**

```
pwsh read.pwsh < input.in

the input is getting printed
```

**Environment data**

```
OS Details        :  Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Poweshell Version :  PowerShell 6.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an advanced user of powershell, but the script should have the extension .ps1. I see you using pwsh as an extension and I think that the system cannot read the file correctly.

Comment: tried using .ps1 extension too but still it is showing the same behaviour.